# No error_log created on Apache

Tags: php, apache, logging

I'm using the error_log(); function to log significant problems/warnings in my script. Normally an error_log file was created on my shared server, in the same dir as the file that caused the problem.

However, since I'm moved to a virtual private server, error_log files aren't created anymore. I really have no idea about how to solve this problem.. Already tried ini_set('log_errors','1'); and ini_set('error_log','error_log.log'); but they just don't appear.

Anybody knows what to do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: neither `error_log` nor `ini_set('error_log', ...)` has anything to do with apache, you might need to refine your question

Comment: dear @Robin were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @syedrakib Yes, see the chosen answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have somethink like this:

```
error_log("My error message", 0);
```

Some ways, you'll can explore:

1. Check the second parameters (0) : http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php
2. Is there a global "error_log" in "/var/log/apache2/error_log, with your message
3. If you have a "VirtualHost" defined, have you the "ErrorLog" directive set
4. Is the directory is writable by apache.

If you have :

```
error_log("My error message", 3, 'error_log.log');
```

Your current directory must be writable by apache (the executer of the script).

Aka

Comment: +1 For "current directory must be writable by apache (executer of the script)"